# XSL document() file not found

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xsl file while processing xml file some time I do need several xml file to be include, for that I use document() method, my problem is that all time all xml file which I include are not available online hence my transformation is stop due to file not found!!! does any body help me the best practice for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the XSLT spec leaves it up to the implementation to define how to handle the case when a file referenced by the `document()` function is unavailable.  There is a good discussion of this here:
http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200801/msg00036.html

If you have the option to use XSLT 2.0 you can use the [doc-available() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-doc-available) to test whether a file is available before calling the document() function.

Answer (score 0):

Create a local [Hosts File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) entry for the website(s) that point to your local machine(or dev server).

An example that points www.foo.com and www.bar.com to the local machine:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1   www.foo.com
127.0.0.1   www.bar.com
```

Place sample XML file(s) on your local webserver(in necessary folder structure), so that when testing locally any requests for the files on the remote servers(e.g. http://www.foo.com/file1.html, http://www.bar.com/file2.html) will go to your locally hosted files.